# Error - No Matching Distribution Found for "rain" Package in Python Installation

Tags: python, streamlit

I am encountering an error while trying to install the "rain" package in Python. When I run the command `python3 setup.py install`, I receive the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement rain (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for rain

I have cloned the Git repository using `git clone https://github.com/substantic/rain` and navigated to the cloned directory. However, it seems that there is no compatible distribution available for installation.

Could you please suggest any possible solutions or alternative approaches to successfully install and import the "rain" package in Python?

Comment: Just follow the instructions - https://github.com/substantic/rain#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

As for any other Python libraries, you can start by using pip:

```
pip3 install rain-python
```

Also Andrei had mentioned about [Quick start](https://github.com/substantic/rain#quick-start), that too provides additional information.

Hope this helps!

Best regards,

Chanin